# Cannot use positional argument after named argument error in web.php

Tags: php, laravel

```
Route::get(uri: 'scraper', ["App\Http\Controllers\ScraperController"::class, 'scraper'])->name(name:'scraper');
```

I wrote this line in `web.php`, then I got this error:

> 'Cannot use positional argument after named argument'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to define routes using named arguments when it's not necessary. You should write the following:

```
Route::get('scraper', [App\Http\Controllers\ScraperController::class, 'scraper'])->name('scraper');
```

You can read more about [named arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments) and how they differ from positional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using **named agruments**, can do it as

```php
Route::get(
    uri: 'scraper', 
    action: [App\Http\Controllers\ScraperController::class, 'scraper']
)
->name(name:'scraper');
```

Definition of `Route::get()` is like

```php
/**
 *
 * @param string $uri
 * @param array|string|callable|null $action
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
 */
public static function get($uri, $action = null){}
```